# Custom global Application class breaks with "android.app.Application cannot be cast to"

Tags: android

I have a custom global class which looks like this

```
import android.app.Application;

public class MyApp extends Application {

    public String MainAct;

    public String getMainAct() {
        return MainAct;
    }

    public void setMainAct(String mainAct) {
        MainAct = mainAct;
    }
}
```

I want to preserve a string in this class via another `Activity` in its `onCreate` method.

```
    String local = "myLocalVariable";
    ((MyApp) getApplication()).setMainAct(local); //breaks here!!!
    String name = ((MyApp) getApplication()).getMainAct();
```

It breaks on the marked line with error: `Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.app.Application cannot be cast to com.xxx.yyy.global.MyApp`

I've checked the code for five times and I cannot find error anywhere. Can anyone tell me where the error is?!

Thanks

Answer (score 524, accepted):

The error states that the type of the object returned by `getApplication` is `android.app.Application`. A possible cause for this is that you failed to define the application in the manifest. Make sure that your manifest includes something in the lines of:

```
<application android:name=".MyApp"...
</application>
```

Comment: Hey. I have this added to my manifest. However, it is still giving me a ClassCastException

Comment: Had the same problem minutes ago on Android N, the manifest was correct. Restarted the device - exception was gone. Strange...

Comment: @Somu  clean cache, and close instant run, rebuild project, this worded for me, i think this is a bug of instant run.

Comment: @artkoenig Thank you for Information! Restart fixed the problem. 
I was trying to fix this issue. 

I checked with debugger, `getApplication()` and `getApplicationContext()` could not be casted to my `Application` class.

Answer (score 18):

Another solution for **older Android devices or emulators**. 
You defined an application in the manifest:

```
    <application 
           android:name=".MyApp"...
    </application>
```

but you still have this problem?

**Try to disable instant run:**

1. Disable an Instant run
2. Clean and rebuild the project
3. Remove the app from device and install it again without Instant run