# Android - Passing database and id through activities

Tags: android, database, android-activity

I have 2 android activity's

One where I have a room list, i.e. list of rooms.

The other the room contents. Where all the content of a selected room is displayed.

All I want is for the room id(`r_id`) to be passed through the room list class into the room overview class where I can retreive all its contents from the database.

I've been trying to figure out where i'm going wrong, I think its around line 94 - 101:

```
            selectedRoom = (String) ((TextView) view).getText();
            Cursor c2 = sampleDB.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM tbl_roomDesc WHERE roomName =?", new String[] {selectedRoom});

            if (c2 != null ) {
                if  (c2.moveToFirst()) {
                    do {
                        r_id = c2.getString(c2.getColumnIndex("r_id")); 
                    }while (c2.moveToNext());
                }
            }
            c2.close();
```

Can anyone help me figure out what i'm doing wrong here?

[Here is the source for the room list](http://pastebin.com/vJC3rxQa)

[Here is the source for the room overview](http://pastebin.com/TA21cXGg)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: you need to use `Intent.putExtra()` to pass parameter to another activity.

Comment: also check this answer in case you have large data to pass to an activity http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12819617/issue-passing-large-data-to-second-activity/14706456#14706456

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
     final int roomId = r_id;
     next = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.next);
     next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {

            CreateBuilding.val = "Retrieve";
            sampleDB.close();
            Intent intent2 = new Intent(RoomList.this, TabLayoutActivity.class);
            intent2.putExtra("roomId", roomId);
            setResult(RESULT_OK, intent2);
            finish();
            startActivityForResult(intent2, 0);
        }
    });

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
       if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
          if (data != null) {
            int roomId = data. getIntExtra("roomId", 0);
          }
       }
    }
```

If I have not misunderstood you put the roomId inside the `Intent` and retrieve it inside the `onActivityResult`

Comment: how do I retrieve the roomId in onActivityResult?

Comment: i'm finding it difficult to understand :( first off, where to put onActivityResult?

Comment: I can not find where do you start RoomOverview

Comment: that's clear. My question is Where do you start RoomOverview?

Comment: Altough this is not a bad idea, in practice, it makes more sense to send something to another activity through an intent, and use the `onActivityResult` to retrieve the result of that action. Id go with the answer of SavTheCoder

Comment: Oh, sorry, TabLayoutActivity.class is where I start RoomOverview.                 Intent intent2 = new Intent(RoomList.this, TabLayoutActivity.class); In the next.SetOnClickListener, which then starts up this class http://pastebin.com/STAChwjd which starts up roomOverview

Comment: you should override onActivityResult inside TabLayoutActivity. You should find a way to add the roomId value in the intent fo RoomOverview

Comment: What way could I pass it from inside TablayoutActivity?

Answer (score 1):

To pass data between to `Intent`s, use the `putExtras()` method.

Example:

```
Intent i = new Intent(...);
i.putExtras("roomid", "10");
startActivity(i);
```