# How much data we can transfer through intent in android?

Tags: android, android-intent

How much data we can transfer through `intent` in android.
Here I sending sting as a value. but how much data I can send through `intent`.
Is it change based on Android OS version ?

```
Intent myintent=new Intent(Info.this, GraphDiag.class).putExtra("101", "string");
startActivity(myintent);
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Maximum length of Intent putExtra method? (Force close)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12496700/maximum-length-of-intent-putextra-method-force-close)

Answer (score 2):

The amount of data that you can transfer through intents is approx 1MB

Here is a useful link for you

[Issue: Passing large data to second Activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12819617/issue-passing-large-data-to-second-activity)

Answer (score 0):

Reading this link on google groups i don't see any limits per se.But it also depicts a very important point on the top few responses that

> It has not been documented.

Here's the link... https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=5878

Answer (score 0):

I think we can send approx 100kb because I have did by using two images which are approx 40kb each, and including some text, but my app was crashing because of out of memory exception.

When I used two images with approx 12kb each then it was working fine, but took 1 second to start the second activity. :)

Yes, it also changes based on Android OS version.