# How to pass large data(JSON) between activities in Android?

Tags: android, json, android-activity, realm

I'm using Volley and i can get respose from URL.Response jsonObject is like this
[image: This is response]

I have one problem.I want to pass this data between activities.What is correct way?
I'm using realm database.I inserted this json in my database and another activiti,i select this json.Is this correct way?
Problem is that,when loading has finish,second activity not starting immediately.
This is my java code

```
 getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {

                            realm.executeTransaction(new Realm.Transaction() {
                                @Override
                                public void execute(Realm realm) {
                                    TrainMainDBModel trainMainDBModel = realm.createObject(TrainMainDBModel.class);
                                    try {
                                        trainMainDBModel.setTrainsJson(jsonObject.getString("data"));
                                        trainMainDBModel.setAdults(Integer.parseInt(adultsValue.getText().toString()));
                                        trainMainDBModel.setChild(Integer.parseInt(childValue.getText().toString()));

                                        realm.insertOrUpdate(trainMainDBModel); 
                                        Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), TrainsActivity.class);

                                        startActivity(intent);
                                        getActivity().overridePendingTransition(android.R.anim.fade_in, android.R.anim.fade_out);
                                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                                        e.printStackTrace();
                                    }


                                }
                            });


                        }
```

Is it a possible to start second activity immediately,when i have like this large data?
thanks

Comment: is that compulsory to maintain data offline? What if you manage these data in just single arraylist

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12819617/issue-passing-large-data-to-second-activity

Comment: I'm using Realm @IntelliJAmiya

Comment: @Baggio then Arraylist

Comment: I'm using volley post request and i want to show result in another activity,with intent @Babul Patel

Comment: Do you think arraylist is better then Realm ? I don't thinks so @ IntelliJ Amiya

Comment: Then pass arraylist or your custom model class which must be parcable or serializable

Comment: @Baggio use Parcelable class. best way

Comment: yep! you are right but,in your option is this correct way? AS i said i want to start another activity immediately @Piyush

Comment: @Baggio i am not comparing both the things but i am telling you that if you just want to transfer data from one activity to another activity then just pass it through the Intent and for that you have to make GSON parsing or you can make getter setter of your response and make the array of that model and parse that.

Comment: @Baggio Yes its a right way. Nothing wrong with it

Comment: In second Activity i'm using Gson and i have like this source .            trainsMainClass = gson.fromJson(trainMainDBModels.get(0).getTrainsJson(), TrainsMainClass.class);
 @ Babul Patel

Comment: ArrayList<TrainMainDBModel > = new ArrayList<>();

do this and make a forloop of your data and then add them in first actiivty and then load your second activity. It ll be much faster.

Comment: getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable()  never use this method until it needed...!!!

Comment: and TrainMainDBModel implements Parcelable that's right ? @ Babul Patel

Comment: can you explain why? @BabulPatel

Comment: yahp that's right.

Comment: @element you don't need Parcelable if you're using Realm, unless you have a "transient editable object" that you cannot persist to Realm until it is completed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should execute the transaction on a background thread.

```
                   realm.executeTransactionAsync(new Realm.Transaction() {
                            @Override
                            public void execute(Realm realm) {
                                TrainMainDBModel trainMainDBModel = realm.createObject(TrainMainDBModel.class);
                                try {
                                    trainMainDBModel.setTrainsJson(jsonObject.getString("data"));
                                    trainMainDBModel.setAdults(Integer.parseInt(adultsValue.getText().toString()));
                                    trainMainDBModel.setChild(Integer.parseInt(childValue.getText().toString()));
                                } catch (JSONException e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }


                            }
                        }, new Realm.Transaction.OnSuccess() {
                            @Override
                            public void onSuccess() {
                                 Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), TrainsActivity.class);
                                 startActivity(intent);    
                                 getActivity().overridePendingTransition(android.R.anim.fade_in, android.R.anim.fade_out);
                            }
                        });
```

Then you can query this object by ID in the other activity.

```
  TrainMainDBModel trainMainDbModel = realm.where(TrainMainDBModel.class)
                                           .equalTo("id", getIntent().getExtras().getInt("trainId"))
                                           .findFirst();
```

Answer (score -1):

You are performing realm operation on main thread and that will lag your layout so i advice you to save these data in

Volley's on response method 
+
Create Model of your class
+
Make ArrayList with your model class
+ 
then pass it using intent from one activity

it ll be more quick than REALM DB.

Comment: If you're passing arraylists of data between your intents therefore creating unmanaged copies of your data, then there is no point for you to use Realm as a database

Comment: Yes but i am giving him advice to avoid the use of Realm. Because this situation can easily be managed by arraylist.

Comment: `Yes but i am giving him advice to avoid the use of Realm.` but he **is** using Realm, in which case you shouldn't avoid it? Also, you shouldn't send large data between activities, because you can hit the transaction too large exception limit.