# Sending a extremely largely sized list, through an Intent

Tags: java, android

I have an extremely largely sized list and I want to send it through an Intent.
I keep getting:

```
FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION !!!  (parcel size = 1959784)
```

I have 5720 objects in my list, I have done some research online and it says to split the list up into smaller chunks. So, I did this: (got the same error).

```
intent.putExtra("cards1", list1);
intent.putExtra("cards2", list2);
intent.putExtra("cards3", list3);
intent.putExtra("cards4", list4);
```

You can also make your data into a singleton, but I have never dealt with singletons so I do not know the proper procedure to do this.

If anyone has insight, on how to pass extremely large data sets through an intent, please let me know!

Comment: It might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12819617/issue-passing-large-data-to-second-activity

Comment: easy trick, make the list as String with GSON. now pass the string from one activity to another ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Singleton is just a class that created only once. I.e. you would have `getInstance()` or similar method that will create the instance only if it's null.

Then you can hold the reference to your singleton object in your app class (or create a singleton provider if you're using DI).And that's it.

You can add `List<YourItems> yourList` to your singleton class and do something like `App.getYourSingletonInstance().saveData()` in your source, and then do `App.getYourSingletonInstance().getData()` in your target, after which you can clean it. Happy coding.