# Error by casting a class

Tags: java, class, casting

I have created other class for global variables now I just want to cast it like that:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity1);
    class2 global;

    global = (class2)getApplicationContext();
```

I get error:

> android.app.Application cannot be cast to eu.tools.test_training_home.class2

The `class2`:

```
public class class2 extends Application {

    private String name="name1";
    private int number =0;
```

Comment: You are trying to cast an object from Context class to an Application object. It can be posible.

Comment: Sorry, I mean "can't".

Comment: I suggest that you follow the standard Java naming conventions, @Testiest.

Answer (score 0):

Here `getApplicationContext()` returns an object of class `Context` but not `class2`.

Check https://stackoverflow.com/a/907368/1435132.

See [Custom global Application class breaks with "android.app.Application cannot be cast to"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10607392/1435132)

Comment: i get the error after i have added constuctor to the class2 :
before was no error. 
<blink>

Answer (score -1):

The problem was the Consructor in Class2
into class2, i had 1 constuctor, 2 setter, 2 getter
I have deleted the Constructor, then the error did not come

```
public class class2 extends Application {

private String name ="name1";
private int number =10;

public class2(String name, int number) { // this was the problem
    this.name = name;
    this.number = number;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public void setNumber(int number) {
    this.number = number;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public int getNumber() {
    return number;
}
```

}